# XNA Loop to Draw Multiple Sprites Not Working

Tags: sprite, xna-4.0

Developing a simple XNA game for my semester 1 assignment in college. I've hit a bit of a wall with the draw loop for the enemy sprites, however. As far as I can tell, all the enemy sprites are being added to a list in the game1.cs class, but only the first in the list is being drawn.

This method adds instances of the enemies to the list. Spawn is being incremented per-second in the update method. This makes the enemies spawn sequentially every second until four have been spawned.

```
public void LoadEnemies()
    {
        int randX = rand.Next(0, 1000);
        int randY = rand.Next(0, 500);

        if (spawn >= 1)
        {
            spawn = 0;

            if (enemyList.Count() < 4)
            {
                enemyList.Add(new NM_Enemy(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Wisp1"), new Vector2(randX, randY)));
                enemyList.Add(new NM_Enemy(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Wisp2"), new Vector2(randX, randY)));
                enemyList.Add(new NM_Enemy(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Wisp3"), new Vector2(randX, randY)));
                enemyList.Add(new NM_Enemy(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Wisp4"), new Vector2(randX, randY)));
            } 
        }

        //Checks if enemies in the list have left the level bounds
        for (int i = 0; i < enemyList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!enemyList[i].isVisible)
            {
                enemyList.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Draw Method

```
foreach (NM_Enemy enemy in enemyList)
                    {
                        enemy.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
                    }
```

Update Method

```
foreach (NM_Enemy enemy in enemyList)
                {
                    enemy.Update(gameTime);
                }
```

Comment: What I would do: Use a debugger. I guess you're working with Visual Studio, right? Doubleclick left of the line to set a break point. I would do so inside you draw method, so you can see what is in the list then and which one is drawn at a particular moment. To start debugging, hit F5 (or the debug button on top).

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you've posted and the description of your program don't match exactly. You said that

> enemies spawn sequentially every second until four have been spawned
>   but actually what's happening there is that if there are fewer than four enemies, four are spawned at once. Also, they're all being spawned at `(randX, randY)` without you calling `rand.Next()` in between, which means you have four enemies at exactly the same position. This might explain why you're only seeing one - they're all on top of each other. Try putting a breakpoint on this line

```
enemy.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
```

and take a look at the enemy's position. You'll probably find they're all in the same place. To be sure, swap your `randX` and `randY` values in the `enemyList.Add()` lines for some manually-entered values so you can be certain that their positions are different, and then see where they draw.